# Update fields using fields from another row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a 2 rows:

- Row #1 (LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR = 3) **This row has the field data I need**
- Row #2 (max(LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR) = 6) **This row has fields I want to update**

Example of what I have (not the full table):

```
LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR | EMPLID  | DNT_CHNG_THS | LN_ACTION_DT | TRNSFR_BATCH | more...
----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------
              3 | 1234567 |          abc |  13-JAN-2015 | TB3399999203 |
              6 | 1234567 |          xyz |  14-JAN-2015 | TB4820000000 |
```

Example of what I want the update to be:

```
LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR | EMPLID  | DNT_CHNG_THS | LN_ACTION_DT | TRNSFR_BATCH | more...
----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------
              3 | 1234567 |          abc |  13-JAN-2015 | TB3399999203 |
              6 | 1234567 |          xyz |  13-JAN-2015 | TB3399999203 |
```

**Here's the issue I'm seeing:** Right now, my SQL works golden, but I'm not happy with the way it's constructed. If I want to add more fields to change, it will continue to grow in size and continually get more difficult to maintain (having to change a number of fields).

**How can I re-write/condense this so it performs the same task, but is more efficient and cleaner?**

```
update PS_AG_LOAN_DISB_ACTN3 t1
   set t1.LN_ACTION_STATUS = 'B',
       t1.LN_ACTION_DT = (select LN_ACTION_DT
                            from PS_AG_LOAN_DISB_ACTN3
                           where EMPLID = '1234567'
                             and ITEM_TYPE = '913000300110'
                             and LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR = 3),
       t1.TRNSFR_BATCH = (select TRNSFR_BATCH
                            from PS_AG_LOAN_DISB_ACTN3
                           where EMPLID = '1234567'
                             and ITEM_TYPE = '913000300110'
                             and LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR = 3                    
 where t1.EMPLID = '1234567'
   and t1.LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR = (select max(LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR)
                               from PS_AG_LOAN_DISB_ACTN3
                              where EMPLID = '1234567'
                                and ITEM_TYPE = '913000300110'
                                and LN_ACTION_STATUS = 'R');
```

Comment: what field you're intent to update to other? and depend what field ? emplid don't show like your table above.

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam I'm looking to updated `LN_ACTION_DT` and `TRNSFR_BATCH` for now. But in the future plan to add several more fields.

Comment: It looks like you want to use `merge`.

Comment: no, i guess it more efficient if you use Pipelined Function to update that, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's take a look in my sample code, sorry I don't have time to test this code before. But you can tell me what's going on.

First, you create a type for your table instead, then you create a function to update the data you wanted.

```
CREATE TYPE testobj AS OBJECT
{
    LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR NUMBER,
    LN_ACTION_DT DATA,
    TRNSFR_BATCH  VARCHAR2(100)
};

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TESTUP(a number, b date, c varchar2)
RETURN testobj IS
BEGIN
    RETURN NEW testobj(
        LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR => a,
        LN_ACTION_DT => b,
        TRNSFR_BATCH => c
    );
END;

UPDATE (SELECT tbl.*, TESTUP(LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR,LN_ACTION_DT,TRNSFR_BATCH) fun_ret FROM PS_AG_LOAN_DISB_ACTN3 tbl) new_value
SET 
    new_value.LN_ACTION_DT = new_value.fun_ret.LN_ACTION_DT,
    new_value.TRNSFR_BATCH = new_value.fun_ret.TRNSFR_BATCH
WHERE MAX(LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR) == 6
```

the data supply for update function is your data LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR = 3, and the function will process it to produce value for your LN_DISB_SEQ_NBR = 6.

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of DBMSs, you can just write a query with the (self)join, then convert that to an `update` statement with a minimum of effort. But Oracle doesn't allow joins in an update statement.

So we cheat.

First, write the query as a join. If nothing else, we can see the row(s) we want to change matched with the corresponding row containing the data to change it to.

```
select  *
from    LoanActions la1
join    LoanActions la2
    on  la2.Emp_ID = 1234567
    and la2.Seq_No = 3
where   la1.Emp_ID = 1234567
    and la1.Seq_No =(
        select  Max( Seq_No )
        from    LoanActions
        where   Emp_ID = 1234567
            and Action_Status = 'R');
```

Table **la1** contains the data to change, **la2** the data to change it to. Now just write the `update` in a form Oracle allows. In the `set` clause, list the fields to change and a subquery to provide the new data. This will be **la2** above and the `where` clause of the subquery will contain the join criteria from the query. The `where` clause of the `update` statement mainly consists of an `exists` requirement with a (possibly correlated) subquery providing a list of key values to match the rows you want updated. This will closely match the `where` clause of your existing `update` statement. *Oracle requires these to be key values.*

The finished statement then, is:

```
update  LoanActions la1
    set la1.Action_Status = 'B',
        (la1.Action_Date, la1.Xfer_Batch )=(
        select  la2.Action_Date, la2.Xfer_Batch
        from    LoanActions  la2
        where   la2.Emp_ID = 1234567
            and la2.Seq_no = 3 )
where   exists(
        select  Max( Seq_No )
        from    LoanActions
        where   Emp_ID = 1234567
            and Action_Status = 'R'
            and Emp_ID = 1234567 );
```

Note that this is based on the scant data you provided. Your `update` statement refers to fields you omitted from the sample data so I had to make up something. (And I trimmed just a bit from the object names.) So the statement may well require some slight adjustment in your environment. But this gives you a starting point if nothing else.

Note also that to add columns to be modified, just add them to the `set` list.