# PL/SQL Update table using column data from one table, based on equality between different tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update

Basically, I have 2 tables: EMPLOYEES, DBPZIP.

I need to update column ZIP from table EMPLOYEES, using the column ZIP from DBPZIP based on two statements:

EMPLOYEES LOCATION has to be equal do DBPZIP LOCATION and DBPZIP DEPARTMENT has to be 'Store'

I tried in two ways so far:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE           insertZip IS

BEGIN

 UPDATE EMPLOYEES
  SET EMPLOYEES.ZIP =               ( SELECT DPBZIP.POSTCODE
                                      FROM DPBZIP
                                      WHERE DPBZIP.DEPARTMENT = 'Store')

  WHERE DPBZIP.LOCATION = EMPLOYEES.LOCATION;

END;
```

Second way:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE           insertZip IS

  UPDATE EMPLOYEES
  SET EMPLOYEES.ZIP =               ( SELECT DPBZIP.POSTCODE
                                      FROM DPBZIP
                                      WHERE DPBZIP.DEPARTMENT = 'Store'
                                      AND DPBZIP.LOCATION = EMPLOYEES.LOCATION);

END;
```

When I put both DBPZIP inside the select statement, I get single-row subquery returns more than one row.

If I put one outside, I get invalid identifier.

Comment: This link would help you http://psoug.org/reference/update.html  (see Update based on a query returning multiple values and Correlated Updates)

Comment: Your "second way" requires only additional condition for update: UPDATE .. WHERE DPBZIP.LOCATION = EMPLOYEES.LOCATION;

Comment: First, write a query that contains both the data you want to change and the values you want to change it to. A procedure for changing that to an update statement can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182852/update-fields-using-fields-from-another-row/28206301#28206301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First way:
It is not syntatically correct because EMPLOYEES alias does not exist in scope of UPDATE statement.

Second way:
You got Single Row subquery returns more than one row because using '=' in SQL statements you need one value on right hand side of equation. Assuming that one location (DBZIP.LOCATION) returns only one (DBZIP.POSTCODE) you can limit rows returned by adding predicate ROWNUM = 1 or adding DISTINCT in select clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have a `COMMIT` statement inside your procedure. That doesn't strike me as a particularly good idea if you're only updating one row. Second, there is another issue with your query aside from the one pointed out by @Kamil; even if you limit the number of rows returned by the subquery, `EMPLOYEES.zip` will be set to `NULL` whenever there isn't a corresponding record in `DBZIP` for that value of `department` and `location`. Maybe that is acceptable in this instance, but I would rewrite the query as follows.

```
UPDATE employees e
   SET e.zip = ( SELECT MAX(d.postcode) FROM dpbzip d
                  WHERE d.department = 'Store'
                    AND d.location = e.location )
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM dpbzip d
                 WHERE d.department = 'Store'
                   AND d.location = e.location );
```

Note I am using table aliases above so I don't have to type the table names over and over again. Also note that I am using an aggregate (in this case, `MAX()`) to ensure I return only one row in the subquery. (The subquery in the `WHERE EXISTS` clause can return more than one row with no problems.)